# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.dg.test.analytics.AnalyticsViewModel

Tags: android, debugging, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

Created ViewModel, activity with hilt injections properly.

But when i am using viewmodel in composable, its giving this error on runtime

```
@Composable
internal fun GalleryPage(
   analyticsViewModel: AnalyticsViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
```

Cannot create an instance of class com.glance.wallpaper.analytics.AnalyticsViewModel
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:324)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:306)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:280)
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:116)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:215)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get$default(ViewModel.kt:195)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:120)
at com.dg.test.ui.compose.settings.GalleryPageKt.GalleryPage(GalleryPage.kt:299)

Tried debugging viewModel annotations, checked calling places, dependency etc.

Answer (score -1):

After Debugging this, found the cause.
Since analytics is a separate module, and there i only added hilt's base dependency

```
com.google.dagger:hilt-android
```

With this, all process in other modules, dependencies will work.

But analytics module has missing dependencies for compose and compiler

```
com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler
androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose
androidx.hilt:hilt-work:$versions.hiltWorker
```

adding them, it compiled and worked like a charm